# Types don't unify using a type class and a type family

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass, type-families

Consider the snippet

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Proxy

monadify' :: forall m sig. (Monad m, Sig sig) => Proxy sig -> Monadify m sig
monadify' p = monadify p (return () :: m ())

type family Monadify f a where
  Monadify f (a -> r) = a -> Monadify f r
  Monadify f a = f a

class Sig sig where
    monadify :: Monad m => Proxy sig -> m () -> Monadify m sig
```

I've given no instances, but an example usage would be `f :: Int -> String -> Bool, monadify' f :: Int -> String -> IO Bool`.

It fails to typecheck with the following error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Monadify m sig’
            with actual type ‘Monadify m0 sig0’
NB: ‘Monadify’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variables ‘m0’, ‘sig0’ are ambiguous
In the ambiguity check for the type signature for ‘monadify'’:
  monadify' :: forall (m :: * -> *) sig.
               (Monad m, Sig sig) =>
               Monadify m sig
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the type signature for ‘monadify'’:
  monadify' :: forall m sig. (Monad m, Sig sig) => Monadify m sig
```

Intuitively I'd say that it should typecheck, but GHC gets confused by the type family, which is not annotated as injective (I'd rather not for backwards compatibility). It could recover the preimage from the `m ()` and the `Proxy` though, so I don't really know what's the problem here.

**Edit:**

As the error message suggests, I could throw in `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, which in my case fixes all problems. But I don't know the consequences of using that extension, plus I'd rather know why my example doesn't typecheck.

I have a feeling that it has to do with the unifier first trying to unify the `Monadify m sig`s, thereby inferring that it can't prove that the `sig`s and `m`s are identical. Although the unifier just needed to look at the passed arguments to know that they are identical, so that might be where `AllowAmbiguousTypes` helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with `monadify'`, not `monadify`.

Suppose you are calling

```
monadify' :: forall m sig. (Monad m, Sig sig) => Monadify m sig
```

here there are no proxies around so, without assuming `Monadify` injective, it is impossible for the compiler to know what `m,sig` should be instantiated to. That is also needed to understand what instances `(Monad m, Sig sig)` should be used.

Try instead working with

```
monadify' :: forall m sig. (Monad m, Sig sig) 
          => Proxy m -> Proxy sig -> Monadify m sig
```

Also note that `Monadify` is *not* injective:

```
Monadify ((->) Bool) (IO Char)      ~ Bool -> IO Char
Monadify IO          (Bool -> Char) ~ Bool -> IO Char
```

---

If you use `AllowAmbiguousTypes` the following does not type check:

```
test :: forall m sig. (Monad m, Sig sig)
     => Proxy sig -> Proxy m -> Monadify m sig
test t _ = monadify' t
-- Type variable m0 is ambiguous
```

We can however fix it by passing an explicit type argument `m`:

```
test :: forall m sig. (Monad m, Sig sig)
     => Proxy sig -> Proxy m -> Monadify m sig
test t _ = monadify' @ m t
```

Personally, I'd try to remove all proxies and use type arguments instead, since I find it much cleaner, even if that requires ambiguous types.

Comment: Ahh, of course. I ninjaedited the question inbetween, so I'm actually passing a proxy for `sig` now (a `Tagged` in my actual use case). That should compensate for the missing injectivity, namely the FunDep `(Monadify m sig) sig -> m` should hold. With that knowledge, is it safe to use `AllowAmbiguousTypes`? See also my edit above.

Comment: Specifically, I'd like to know if any of `AllowAmbiguousTypes` might leak out to calling modules, giving them a hard time figuring out type errors. I know that it works just fine for my concrete uses in GHCI, but am unsure if that's the general case.

Comment: Also note that `type family Monadify f a = r | r a -> f where ...` is not supported, yet: on the LHS of `->` only a single `r` is allowed. Hence, we can not even state the lesser injectivity property.

Comment: @SebastianGraf Well, the users will need to specify `m` in some way if there's an ambiguity. See my edit.

Comment: OK, so I'll stick with ambiguous types. Seems to be future proof given explicit type arguments in GHC 8 and also works quite well for what I tested it with.